# SQL change a table into another format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
Faculty  Program                Number_of_enrolled
Science  Financial Modelling    25
Science  Actuarial Science      30
Science  Statistics             28
Science  Biology                16
```

I want to use SQL to change the table into something like this:

```
Faculty  Financial Modelling  Actuarial Science  Statistics  Biology
Science  25                   30                 28          16
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    faculty,
    max(case when program = 'Financial Modelling' then number_of_enrolled end) [Financial Modelling],
    max(case when program = 'Actuarial Science' then number_of_enrolled end) [Actuarial Science],
    max(case when program = 'Statistics' then number_of_enrolled end) Statistics,
    max(case when program = 'Biology' then number_of_enrolled end) Biology
from mytable 
group by faculty
```

Comment: Why do we use max function? I don't get it.

Comment: @VivHuang: we need aggregation to reduce the numbers of records in the resultset (we want one record per `faculty`. `max()` is an aggregate function; the `case` expression will return only a value when the condition is matched, and `null` for other records in the group; then, `max()` ignores null and return the only matching value. This is a typical method to pivot a dataset in pure sql. Another good thing is that it works accross most, if not all, RDBMS (unlinke vendor-specific pivot functions).

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. This is the simplest way to do this. And conditional aggregation is almost always a bit better than pivot for performance, not to mention far less obtuse for syntax.

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed that this should not get the downvote (+1).  Conditional Aggregation offers a bit more flexibility, but you're a smart guy and I don't understand your disdain for PIVOT

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for the kind words. I don't have a disdain for PIVOT. I just find the syntax extremely cumbersome and it doesn't offer any benefit that I have ever found. It is just horrific if you need multiple groups when you have multiple PIVOTS in a query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Pivot

```
select * from test
pivot (max (num) for program in 
([Financial Modelling],[Actuarial Science],[Statistics],[Biology])) 
as Programs
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0159f/3

Answer (score 0):

Similar to GMB you can use dynamic sql as below to do the same pivot to get all the columns

```
declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @cols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(Program) from facultytable group by Program for xml path('')),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'select faculty, ' + @cols + ' from ( ' + ' select faculty, Program, Number_of_enrolled from facultytable ) a ' 
SET @Query = @query + ' pivot (max([Number_of_enrolled]) for Program in (' + @cols + ')) p '

--select @query --Execute below by uncommenting after checking the query
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Output as below:

```
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| faculty | Actuarial Science | Biology | Financial Modelling | Statistics |
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
| Science |                30 |      16 |                  25 |         28 |
+---------+-------------------+---------+---------------------+------------+
```

Code here: https://rextester.com/LFSP20314